# ATI driver on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ati

To begin with - I've searched other questions with no luck.

So: I've got a 12.10 and trying to set ATI drivers using [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI).

After installing and rebooting I've got a blank desktop and used this:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx*`

to get back, but nothing happened! I'm stuck with this empty desktop.

What can I do to get back to open source drivers?

`lspci -vvnn | grep VGA` tells me that I have `Mobility Radeon HD 4500/5100 series` card.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the AMD web site direct.

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx

Every time they update the Kernel you have to re install the drivers. It's a pain. But running their drivers means you simply run their package and its pretty much one step process.

Comment: nope. used this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200 but 13.1 lecagy driver. still the same